# Query on datetime fields with milliseconds gives wrong result in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, datetime

I'm running into an odd bug using datetime fields in SQL Server 2005. The datetime field shows up with millisecond-level accuracy, but it looks like the milliseconds are not always used. Here's my test query:

```
SELECT col1, YEAR(col1) AS yr, MONTH(col1) AS mn, DAY(col1) AS dy
FROM mytable
WHERE col1 >= '2009-12-31 00:00:00.0' AND col1 <= '2009-12-31 23:59:59.999'
ORDER BY col1
```

In my results I get:

```
 col1                       |  yr  | mn | dy
----------------------------+------+----+----
 2009-12-31 00:00:00:00.000 | 2009 | 12 | 31
 2010-01-01 00:00:00:00.000 | 2010 |  1 |  1
```

The problem is that I got the 2010-01-01 date, even though that shouldn't be less than or equal to "2009-12-31 23:59:59.999". But if I change the query to use "2009-12-31 23:59:59.99**8**" it works OK (no 2010 datetimes are returned).

Is this a bug, or is this just how SQL Server works? If this is how it works, is there some reason for it? I ran into this migrating some queries from MySQL, where this works as expected (even though MySQL doesn't even store the milliseconds!).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`SQL Server` stores time part as number of `1/300` second long ticks from the midnight.

`23:59:59.999` gets rounded to the nearest tick which happens to be `00:00:00.000` of the next day.

```
SELECT  CAST(CAST('2009-12-01 00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME) AS BINARY(8)),
        CAST(CAST('2009-12-01 23:59:59.997' AS DATETIME) AS BINARY(8)),
        CAST(CAST('2009-12-01 23:59:59.999' AS DATETIME) AS BINARY(8))



0x00009B8F 00000000    0x00009B8F 018B81FF    0x00009B90 00000000
```

In the first value, the date part, `0x9B8F` (`39823`) is the number of days since `Jan 1st, 1900`, and the time part, `0`, is the number of ticks since midnight.

In the second value, `0x018B81FF` (`25919999`, or `24 * 60 * 60 * 300 - 1`) is the maximal possible number of ticks since midnight.

Finally, the third value has the `0` in the time part and the date part increased by one.

Comment: If it's an option in your code, use less than: " ... AND col1 < '2010-1-1 00:00:00.0'

Comment: Just to add the reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx

`Accuracy : Rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds`

Comment: 3.33-millisecond ticks. i wonder why on earth they chose that? if they are storing it as a 32-bit date and 32-bit time, the total number of milliseconds in a day is only 0x05265c00, which fits in a 32-bit integer with room to spare.

Comment: SQL Server **2008** has DATETIME2 or TIME, which stores times with an accuracy of down to 100ns - just in case you need that.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a bug. It's perfectly expected behavior.
look here: [datetime and smalldatetime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258277(SQL.80).aspx)

You should change it to

```
WHERE col1 >= '2009-12-31 00:00:00.0' AND col1 < '2010-01-01'
```

Answer (score 1):

With all floating point types, and a date/time is actually a kind of floating point value, you should try to avoid equality comparisons like that.

So instead of:

```
WHERE x <= 10.999
```

you should do:

```
WHERE x <  11
```

so instead of listing up the last value you want included, you list the first value you want excluded, generally this works better when the boundaries are whole numbers, since they have a much larger chance of being accurately representable in the domain of the type.

In your particular case, I would change it to:

```
WHERE ... col1 < '2010-01-01 00:00:00.000'
               ^
               |              ^-- changed to 2010
               ^-- changed <= to <
```

Answer (score 1):

This is also why the 'Between' comparison operator is not recommended for dates.   'Between' is an inclusive comparison (values that match both ends are included) and as recommended above, you should be doing an exclusive version of between such as
                  bottomvalue < testvalue < topvalue