# SQL Millisecond Precision

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I am storing a time in a DATETIME field in SQL but when I try delete anything less than that value it is actually deleting that value. so for example:

I have a value 2015-06-24 16:32:42.**243** in a table
when I run the below query, it deletes the value even though it is not in it's range. Why?

```
DELETE FROM MyTable
WHERE  MyDate <= '2015-06-24 16:32:42.242'
```

Is there a precision issue?

Comment: Further reading: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2049656/1225845

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Values in the legacy `datetime` datatype are only stored to approx 1/300 of a second precision.

valid ms endings are `0`,`3`,`7` anything else will be rounded to the nearest of those (`5` is equidistant between `3` and `7` and is rounded up to `7`, this is the only 2ms adjustment).

So `.242` is rounded up to `.243` when implicitly cast to `datetime`

If you are on SQL Server 2008+ you can use `datetime2(3)` for full ms precision.

Or just use

```
DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE MyDate < '2015-06-24 16:32:42.243'
```